# struts2 dojo error : static resource not accessible anymore

Tags: jquery, dojo, struts2

Im' trying ajax with struts2 and dojo doing something very simple :

in the jsp :

```
...
<sx:head/>
...
<sx:div href="/myUrl.action">Loading ...</sx:div>
...
```

I works perfectly, fetching the URL and so on. BUT, when I reload the context by modifying the jsp (I have a context with the reloadable="true" flag), it does not work anymore.

The reason seems to be that the following URL is not accessible anymore :
http://myserver.com/myContext/struts/dojo/struts_dojo.js

leads to the following exception :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DefaultStaticContentLoader.findStaticResource(DefaultStaticContentLoader.java:162)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeStaticResourceRequest(ExecuteOperations.java:62)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:86)
    com.cellectis.servlet.common.SessionRecorder.doFilter(SessionRecorder.java:68)
```

(it was accessible when it worked).

I tried struts2-jquery and had exactly the same javascript accessibility problem.

My web.xml extract :

```
...
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/st2fr/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/struts/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
...
```

I do not have a simple url-pattern of /* because there are some non-struts servlet on the same context. /st2fr is the namespace where my struts application are, and /struts/* is to have accessibility to the dojo javascript.

I'm using struts-2.3.1 on tomcat-6.0.13

Has anybody an idea of why this curious behaviour or what to do ?

Thanks for your attention.

Aymeric

Comment: In fact, it is the simple change of the date of the struts.xml file that is the cause of the problem. It contains : <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/> (development site). url-pattern can be /*, the problem stays exactly the same